# translate curl to .net web request

Tags: http, curl, http-headers, httpwebrequest

Here is a curl command from documentation:

```
curl -g "http://ip.ip.ip.ip/test/xyz.jpg?attributes=size"
```

Can i just translate it to HttpReqeust like this?

```
UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder("http", "ip.ip.ip.ip", 80, /test/xyz.jpg);
Uri uri = builder.Uri;
System.Net.HttpWebRequest request =
                ((HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri + "?attributes=system::size"));
```

The UriBuilder is just pseudocode. I get an exception: Bad Request

Do i have to use the request Headers to add the attributes? or how do this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just try:

```
UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder("http", "ip.ip.ip.ip", 80, "/test/xyz.jpg");
Uri uri = builder.Uri;
System.Net.WebClient cli = new System.Net.WebClient();
cli.DownloadFile(uri.ToString() + "?attributes=size", "C:\\xyz.jpg");
```

You can use HttpWebRequest, but there is a lot more code to write in order to download a file. ALso be careful to [`System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx) any query strings if that is required.

Incidentally, why do you change `?attributes=size` to `?attributes=system::size` between your two samples?